# Android - Stripe payment in stripe.createToken deprecated

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

Google play store giving me warning to upgrade stripe SDK to 16.9.0 version,
Now my code in createToken() method not working.

```
  Stripe stripe = new Stripe(this, Const.STRIPE_PUB_KEY);

    stripe.createToken(
            card,
            new TokenCallback() {
                public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                   
                    // Send token to your server
                    String stripeToken = token.getId();
                    Log.d("stripeToken", stripeToken);
               
                }

                public void onError(Exception error) {
                   
                }
            }
    );
```

Now i have changed `createToken()` to `createCardToken()`

```
Stripe stripe = new Stripe(this, Const.STRIPE_PUB_KEY);

    stripe.createCardToken(
            card,
            new TokenCallback() {
                public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                   
                    // Send token to your server
                    String stripeToken = token.getId();
                    Log.d("stripeToken", stripeToken);
               
                }

                public void onError(Exception error) {
                   
                }
            }
    );
```

[image]

Now working fine but `createCardToken()` method showing me as method will be deprecate.

any other way to i can create card token? or other policy upgraded for card token?

Comment: Well, they have [another `createCardToken` method](https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/stripe/com.stripe.android/-stripe/create-card-token.html) that takes almost the same parameters and isn't marked as deprecated. So have you tried switching to that one?

Comment: @Michael i have upated my question with image. So you can see this

Comment: It's deprecated in newer versions of the SDK yes because you should be using PaymentIntents and PaymentMethods instead, but that's a bigger change. You can just upgrade to any version of the library from v14.3.0 onwards to fix that Play Store warning, it doesn't _have_ to be very latest 16.9.0 if you're not in a position to fully migrate right now.